# How to create a simple variable alternator triggered by onclick?

Tags: javascript

This seems like a simple thing, my problem is that I learn things randomly, not in order.

I'm after a simple cycling/alternator where pushing something switches from one state to another eg. 1,2,1,2,1,etc...

So

I have my object to be clicked

```
<div onclick="alternateVar();">Click me</div>
```

Then I have the function/variable declaration/properties
I am not sure which variable setup I should choose I have shown three cases.

```
<script>

// check current value of variable 
alert(mode);

// variable declaration

var mode = {value=1};       // method one
var mode = new Number();    // method two
var mode = 1;               // method three

// alternate variable 

function alternateVar() {

// attempt 1

if(mode.value == 1){
mode.value(2); // set new value to variable
}else {
mode.value(1);
}

// attempt 2

if(mode.value == 1){
var mode = 2; // overwrite? is it global?
}else {
var mode = 1;
}

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7es160so/). I just used a ternary operator! Is this what you needed?

```
var number = 1;

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = alternateVar;

function alternateVar() {
    number = number == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    alert(number);
}
```

Comment: Hey that's great, curious if you could explain how that question mark works?

Comment: Actually nevermind I just looked it up, cool! I didn't know about this operator.

Comment: What do you make of this notice that I see in the console? mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

Comment: Yeah mine seems to only work on the first click. I'll create a partial fiddle. Your fiddle accomplished what I was looking to do, I don't know why mine doesn't work, perhapts outside of the scope?

Comment: Yeah that was it, I extended the bracket to cover all of the changes that I wanted and now the alternating works and the changes happen. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: sorry to continue this, I'm curious why it only works after the first click eg. the first click doesn't work. Is that a dom/load thing?

Comment: It works for me! It's instantiated as 1, first click changes to 2, and vice versa for infinity :)